# Scrapy: Save response.body as html file?

Tags: python, django, scrapy, web-crawler

My spider works, but I can't download the body of the website I crawl in a .html file. If I write self.html_fil.write('test') then it works fine. I don't know how to convert the tulpe to string.

I use Python 3.6

**Spider:**

```
class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "example"
    allowed_domains = ['google.com']
    start_urls = ['http://google.com/']

    def __init__(self):
        self.path_to_html = html_path + 'index.html'
        self.path_to_header = header_path + 'index.html'
        self.html_file = open(self.path_to_html, 'w')

    def parse(self, response):
        url = response.url
        self.html_file.write(response.body)
        self.html_file.close()
        yield {
            'url': url
        }
```

**Tracktrace:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line
 653, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "c:\Users\kv\AtomProjects\example_project\example_bot\example_bot\spiders
\example.py", line 35, in parse
    self.html_file.write(response.body)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

Comment: Try response.body.decode("utf-8")

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actual problem is you are getting byte code. You need to convert it to string format. there are many ways for converting byte to string format.
 You can use

```
 self.html_file.write(response.body.decode("utf-8"))
```

instead of

```
  self.html_file.write(response.body)
```

also you can use

```
  self.html_file.write(response.text)
```

Comment: I would recommend using `response.text` which is Unicode already (since the encoding might not be UTF-8), instead of `response.body.decode("utf-8")`

Answer (score 7):

The correct way is to use `response.text`, and not `response.body.decode("utf-8")`. To quote [documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.TextResponse.text):

> Keep in mind that `Response.body` is always a bytes object. If you want the unicode version use `TextResponse.text` (only available in `TextResponse` and subclasses).

and

> text: Response body, as unicode.
>
> The same as `response.body.decode(response.encoding)`, but the result is cached after the first call, so you can access `response.text` multiple times without extra overhead.
>
> Note: `unicode(response.body)` is not a correct way to convert response body to unicode: you would be using the system default encoding (typically ascii) instead of the response encoding.

Answer (score 5):

Taking in consideration responses above, and making it as much *pythonic* as possible adding the use of the `with` statement, the example should be rewritten like:

```
class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "example"
    allowed_domains = ['google.com']
    start_urls = ['http://google.com/']

    def __init__(self):
        self.path_to_html = html_path + 'index.html'
        self.path_to_header = header_path + 'index.html'

    def parse(self, response):
        with open(self.path_to_html, 'w') as html_file:
            html_file.write(response.text)
        yield {
            'url': response.url
        }
```

But the `html_file` will only accessible from the `parse` method.